# How to add validation of the field after the submit button

Tags: jquery, jeditable

In my application I use jQuery plug-in [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable).

I have to add a message box when trying to submit an empty field, for example: *FIELD MUST NOT BE EMPTY!*

**HTML:**

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="edit">123456789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="edit">132456789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="edit">123456789</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.edit').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php');
 });
```

[Code on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/v6WVa/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to be fighting this plugin a little bit to do what you want. Here's a basic example of what you describe, using the instructions from the plugin on how to submit to a function rather than a URL.

http://jsfiddle.net/nate/v6WVa/3/

```
// On page load, set the original value for each item
$('.edit').each(function (i, item) {
    var $item = $(item);

    $item.attr('data-original-value', $item.text());
});

$('.edit').editable(function (value, settings) {
    // Perform any checks of the value here
    if (!value) {
        alert('Field must not be empty');
        return $(this).data('original-value');       
    } else {
        // Make your own ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: {
                value: value
            },
            complete: function () {
                console.log('saved');
            }
        });

        // On success, change the data-original-value to reflect
        // the new value        
        $(this).attr('data-original-value', value);
        return value;
    }
}, {
    onblur: 'submit'
});
```

In your function, you can do whatever kind of logic you want to test the value, pop alerts or messages, or what you will. Then you need to make an AJAX call on your own to save the value.

Preventing users from inputting a blank value makes it slightly trickier, too. The plugin doesn't seem to provide a way to interrupt submission events, so the best I could figure out was to keep track of your last valid value and return that in the event of a value (such as being blank) that you don't like.

Comment: @Nate Hi. The plugin prevent the submit. I use it in order to validate the min / max length of my fields. If, for example, one of my field not  match minlenght or maxlenght attributre rules the form isn't submitted and I display a custom error.

Comment: @mserioli could you give an example?

Comment: @Nate by pressing the ENTER - nothing happens... ((

Comment: Sorry.. I've found that in my previous comment I've pasted a link that in not correct.. here you are the correct one: http://jqueryvalidation.org/ You can find an example on docs! Tell me if could be useful to you!

Comment: @archi_sova - Check again - I think an update I made broke that functionality without my realizing it.